# What to prefer between spin_lock_init and DEFINE_SPINLOCK AND WHEN

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a question. Is DEFINE_SPINLOCK preferable over spin_lock_init? What are the advantages of former over latter, and what are the possible draw-backs?

Comment: This is a good question to try and answer by reading the source code yourself.  Here is a start: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/spinlock.h

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a static data structure, DEFINE_SPINLOCK lets you declare a spinlock variable and initialize it in one line.  However for anything allocated at runtime, for example when a spinlock is embedded in a bigger structure, then you need to allocate the memory and then call spin_lock_init().

I guess I would say that I prefer DEFINE_SPINLOCK when it is possible to use it.  The advantage is tiny (compile-time initialization vs. runtime initialization, a couple lines less of code) but there's no real drawback.  As I mentioned above, it's often not possible to use DEFINE_SPINLOCK, though.